# Use Operators on Multiple Conditions in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to control the creation of a resource with two Cloudformation `Condition` specifications.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Conditions:
    PROD: ...
    REGION_A:...
```

These conditions work fine to regulate the creation of resources on their own, but I cannot figure out how to use them both in conjunction without defining a single purpose built Condition that melds the two.

```
ResourceA:
    ...
    Condition: {"Fn::And": [{"Condition": "PROD"},{"Condition": "REGION_A"}]}
```

I have tried a few combitionations and variations of the above, but get an error like the following.

```
Fn::And object requires a list of at least 2 and at most 10 boolean parameters
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating new condition which depends on those two is the only way to solve it.

```
Conditions:
    PROD: ...
    REGION_A:..
    PROD_REGION: {"Fn::And": [{"Condition": "PROD"},{"Condition": "REGION_A"}]}
```

Unfortunately I cannot find proofs in the documentation.

Comment: Yeah that's what I've found too. Too bad.

Comment: Here is the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-and